# SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/example.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, certificate, key

#### Problem Statement:

I've wanted to change the SSL certificate, because I've changed my server so I had to create a new CSR with the different name as discuss in the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42111969) with this command. And generated the **Privatekey** and **CSR**.

```
$ openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout example_new.key -out example_new.csr
```

Then I'd paste the CSR to **Re-Key** in Godaddy portal and received certificate from  Godaddy and then i renamed it to the following as per best practises.

1. `example.com.crt`
2. `intermediate.crt`
3. `example.com.pem`

And then I've concatenated the certificate with signing certificate in right order as discussed in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52261299).

```
$ cat example.com.crt intermediate.crt > bundle_chained.crt
```

---

#### Exception:

Getting following exception while restarting Nginx.

`$ sudo nginx -t`

```
nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/path/example_new.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

---

Here's what I tested:

- The certificate and private key has no trailing spaces.
- I checked the `nginx.conf` and the directives are pointing to the
  correct private key and certificate.
- I've checked md5 hashed of the key and bundle_chained

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in bundle_chained.crt | openssl md5
(stdin)= d91144b76e2fa292e9aee71f10ac8b63

$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in example.key | openssl md5
(stdin)= a4773e7fa31e0bdc7edad15ee5412d3e
```

> Note: Md5 hash are not matching

- Checked bundle_chained.crt using following and figure out that it doesn't look like my as I've specified Maharashtra **ST** and it is showing Arizona which is my CA.

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -text -in bundle_chained.crt


Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            8d:a1:9d:55:8c:d8:as:45
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "GoDaddy.com, Inc.", OU = http://certs.godaddy.com/repository/, CN = Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
        Validity
            Not Before: Aug 20 11:54:25 2020 GMT
            Not After : Aug 19 10:00:10 2022 GMT
        Subject: OU = Domain Control Validated, CN = example.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
....
.....
```

> Note: Please note that it did showing **CN** correct as `example.com` in my case.

---

Thank you for your help. :)