# SSL Client Authentication with Python requests

Tags: python, security, ssl, https, python-requests

I'm using Python's [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/) library to perform [client side authentication with certificates](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#client-side-certificates). The scenario is the following: `CA1` has issued a certificate for an intermediate CA (`CA2`) and `CA2` has issued my client's certificate `CLIENT`. The server I'm connecting to trusts `CA1`'s cert (but does not have `CA2`'s cert). When I use:

```
requests.get('https:..', cert=('/path/CLIENT.cert', '/path/CLIENT.key'))
```

I get an error "certificate verify failed". I assumed that's because the server can not retrieve `CA2`'s cert.

However, I'm unable to find a way to send `CA2`'s cert to the server. If I include it in `CLIENT`, I get an error about private key and cert mismatch. I have also tried to include the chain of certificates in the [`verify`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) parameter but there does not seem to be any difference on the result (as far as I understand, certs in the `verify` parameter are used for server side authentication).

Although I think this must be a quite common scenario, I'm unable to find a solution...

PD: If I verify `CLIENT`'s cert with openssl and the full chain of certificates the validation is successful (so there is no problem with the certificates themselves).

Comment: How about passing _path to the directory containing certs of trusted CAs_ to `verify`?

Comment: Thnks @OluwafemiSule Indeed, I have already tried that without any success (as far as I understand, certs in the verify parameter are used for server side authentication, but not for client side auth.)

Comment: Is `'/path/CLIENT.cert'` a **chained Certificate**? Read about: [How does an SSL certificate chain bundle work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409534/how-does-an-ssl-certificate-chain-bundle-work)

Comment: Yes, I have tried to include the chain into CLIENT.cert, but I obtain an error about private key and cert mismatch whenever I include the intermediate CA's certs into CLIENT.cert. Currently I think there is a problem with the CA's certificate (even though openssl validates them correctly...)

Comment: @stovfl Indeed, `/path/CLIENT.cert` had to be a chained certificate with the first certificate being the client one. In my case, there was a problem with the intermediate CA's cert (openssl validated it correctly but the server was more sensitive and failed to do so). If you want, write this as an answer and I would accept it! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Requests recommends using [`certifi`](https://certifi.io/en/latest/) as a CA bundle. Have you tried installing `certifi`, adding `CA1`, and passing the `certifi` bundle path to `requests`?

Comment: Thanks! As far as I know certifi is used to verify the server's cert in the client machine (the one using requests to make the petition), but the problem I have is with client authentication (that is, the server needs to be able to verify my client's cert).

Comment: So you get this error on the server side? What are you using to receive requests on the server side, then?

Comment: Yes, the server says the certificate is not valid, and I can see it both in the server logs and the response I get from the server (in the client). The server is running java spring. The server trusts `CA1` cert (but does not have the intermediate CA `CA2` cert). I don't know how I can send CA2 to the server so that it can properly validate my client's cert.