# self signed certificate in certificate chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl-certificate

I am trying to send a email through my server so anyone will enter his/her email to my app instantly get an welcome email i'm using nodemailer but i'm getting error in my console click the link to see the error and please explain what does this error means? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQavl.png)

```js
let transporter = nodemialer.createTransport({
    service : 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'gauravrajpoot452@gmail.com',
        pass: 'sonu@12345'
    }
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    let email = req.body.userEmail;

    let mailOptions = {
        from: 'gauravrajpoot452@gmail.com',
        to: email,
        subject: 'Node tutorials',
        text: `Hey gaurav you're a software engineer.`
    } 
    
    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
        else{
            console.log('Email sent' + info.response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: post error in text here please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Openssl : error "self signed certificate in certificate chain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180552/openssl-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain)

Comment: It means you have a self signed certificate in the certificate chain `  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ ` I'm not really clear what other information you need?

Comment: So does it mean that i have to do some auth with gmail or something and sorry maybe i'm not able to make you understand my code error but how can i solve this error?