# Informatica HTTP transformation, End point URL does not give response for GET method

Tags: xmlhttprequest, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am trying to use HTTP transformation for getting response from an api. Here I am not sending any token or credentials for authorization. I am just using blanK text file as source and in HTTP transformation mentioned the URL. Below is mapping

```
SQ(Blank text file)-->HTTP(GET method and URL)-->http response(FlatFile)
```

Kindly correct if I can use blank text file as source since I am not sending any data for GET request. I am getting error as follows in the image[image: session log image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is not about data being sent. The error mentions a problem with the certificate. One of certificates in the chain is self-signed - this means (briefly) it cannot be trusted. Try reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12180552/openssl-error-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chain) for more info.